# database provides mobile device width,heigth and resolution

Tags: mobile, device-detection

I am looking for database that provides mobile device width,height,resolution and pixel aspect ratio based on device maker and device model using java

Answer (score 0):

[51degrees.mobi](http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/Java.aspx) offers Java support. You can interrogate the device properties with it.

Answer (score 0):

The big players are [Device Atlas](https://deviceatlas.com/resources/download-enterprise-api) and [WURFL](http://www.scientiamobile.com/).

Both have APIs that you'll be able to use with Java. However, be warned they aren't free.